# Undefined reference to getprocessmemoryinfo@12

Tags: c, windows, memory-management

I am trying to calculate the primary memory usage for the current process in C language on Windows using:

windows.h
psapi.h

```
PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX pmc;
GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), &pmc, sizeof(pmc));
SIZE_T physMemUsedByMe = pmc.WorkingSetSize;
```

It gives me the error:

> undefined reference to getprocessmemoryinfo@12

Any idea how to fix this? My compiler is mingw32-gcc.exe

Comment: Can you specify the exact platform (Windows version, compiler brand and version)?

Comment: Windows, compiler - mingw32-gcc.exe

Comment: Are you linking the PSAPI library with `-lpsapi`? Can you show your build command?

Comment: I am using:
windows.h
psapi.h

Comment: The library is not the same as a header file (`*.h`). Please show the command you are building your application with.

Comment: how to get that ? I have not mentioned anything in the Linker tab

Answer (score 21):

The header file that declares the function is used by the *compiler* to compile your code. The linker though does need a definition of the external functions that are used. That is typically supplied in an import library. The error message tells you that the linker has no such definition.

Link with

```
-lpsapi
```

to provide the linker with the appropriate import library.

Comment: To end the five year long journey to find out how to accept an answer: Just click the check ✓ icon.