# Error when trying to get the current process memory size on C++, MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, clion, mingw-w64, psapi

When I try to call GetProcessMemoryInfo I get an error:
undefined reference to `GetProcessMemoryInfo'

I've seen this issue:[Undefined reference to getprocessmemoryinfo@12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361083/undefined-reference-to-getprocessmemoryinfo12)

but it doesn't solve mine.

I'm trying to know what is the size of my process in the RAM so to do that I need to use the 'GetProcessMemoryInfo' method.

My problem is that the link breaks when I do that.

CmakeLists.txt:

```
project(maxpath)

set(dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${dir}/build")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static -m64 -lpsapi")

file( GLOB LIB_ALG algorithms/*.hpp )
file( GLOB LIB_DS datastructures/*.hpp )
file( GLOB LIB_LOG include/*.h)

set(GRID_GENERATOR
        ${LIB_ALG}
        ${LIB_DS}
        ${LIB_LOG}
        grid/generator.cpp
        grid/grid.hpp)

set(GRID_SOLVER
        ${LIB_ALG}
        ${LIB_DS}
        ${LIB_LOG}
        grid/main_grid.cpp
        grid/grid.hpp
        include/memory_helper.cpp include/memory_helper.hpp include/fnv.h)
add_executable(gridGenerator ${GRID_GENERATOR})
add_executable(gridSolver ${GRID_SOLVER})
```

You can see that I use the `-lpsapi` argument,

The error I get is:

```
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable "some path...\gridSolver.exe"
CMakeFiles\gridSolver.dir/objects.a(memory_helper.cpp.obj):memory_helper.cpp:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to `GetProcessMemoryInfo'
CMakeFiles\gridSolver.dir/objects.a(memory_helper.cpp.obj):memory_helper.cpp:(.text+0x131): undefined reference to `GetProcessMemoryInfo'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.3-P/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\gridSolver.dir/objects.a(memory_helper.cpp.obj): bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.3-P/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [some path.../gridSolver.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\gridSolver.dir\build.make:121: recipe for target 'some path.../gridSolver.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gridSolver.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:103: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/gridSolver.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gridSolver.dir/rule] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:115: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/gridSolver.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [gridSolver] Error 2
makefile:130: recipe for target 'gridSolver' failed
```

I'm working with CLion and mingw-w64\x86_64-4.8.3-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev2\mingw64

Is there another way of doing this (except of using psapi)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer there is correct. You should link against `psapi`:

```
FIND_LIBRARY (PSAPI Psapi)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(gridSolver ${PSAPI})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(gridGenerator ${PSAPI})
```

Or you can add it manually to the linker flags - you added it to the compiler flags in your example.

Comment: Thanks for ansering, Now I get this error: specify link libraries for target "gridSolver" which is not built by this project.

Comment: Then the example you provided is clearly wrong or you pasted this to the wrong location, because your example clearly has a `gridSolver` target. If you added the `target_link_libraries` before the `add_executable`, please read the cmake docs.

Comment: You are correct, I accedently put it before the add_executable part